# Solución a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, array

El siguiente código compara dos coches por identificador y muestra el coche con mas autonomía(km), al introducir un identificador que no existe muestra un error de "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

¿Cómo se podría hacer para que si el identificador no existe me muestre "identificador no existe pruebe de nuevo"?.

```
    public class Coches {

        int identificador;
        int kilometros;

        public Coches(){}

        public Coches(int identificador, int kilometros) {
            this.identificador = identificador;
            this.kilometros = kilometros;
        }

        public int getIdentificador(){
            return identificador;
        }

        public int getKilometros(){
            return kilometros;
        }
    }

    public class Pruebas{

         public static void main(String[] args) {

             Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

             Coches coche = new Coches();

             // Se almacenan un numero máximo de coches (4).

             Coches array [] = new Coches [4];

             int contador = 0;

             while (contador < array.length) {

                 System.out.println("Introduce el identificador del coche : ");

                 int identificador;
                 int kilometros;

                 System.out.print("Identificador :");
                 identificador = teclado.nextInt();

                 System.out.print("Kilometros :");
                 kilometros = teclado.nextInt();

                 coche = new Coches(identificador,kilometros);

                 array [contador] = coche;
                 contador++;

                 System.out.print("Coche dado de alta");
                 System.out.println();
            }

            System.out.print("Se ha alcanzado el maximo de coches.\n");

            //Busca cual realizo mayor kilometraje:
            int maxKilometros = 0;
            int indiceCoche = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){                  
                if(array[i].getKilometros() > maxKilometros){
                    maxKilometros = array[i].getKilometros();
                    indiceCoche = i;
                }                   
            }

            System.out.print("El coche que ha recorrido más kilometros es:"  + array[indiceCoche].getIdentificador() + " Kilometros: "+ array[indiceCoche].getKilometros() +"\n");


                    System.out.println("Introduce el primer identificador del coche :"); 
                    int idcoche1 = teclado.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("Introduce el segundo identificador del coche :");         
                    int idcoche2 = teclado.nextInt(),
                    indiceCoche1 = -1,
                    indiceCoche2 = -1;



                    for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){       

                       if(array[i].getIdentificador() == idcoche1){
                           indiceCoche1 = i;
                       }
                       if(array[i].getIdentificador() == idcoche2){
                           indiceCoche2 = i;
                       }               
                   }

                    if (array[indiceCoche1].getKilometrosRecorridos().compareTo(array[indiceCoche2].getKilometrosRecorridos()) > 0 ){
                       System.out.print("El coche " + array[indiceCoche1].getIdentificador() +  " tiene mas kilometros recorridos con " + array[indiceCoche1].getKilometrosRecorridos());
                   } else {
                       System.out.print("El coche " + array[indiceCoche2].getIdentificador() +  " tiene mas kilometros recorridos con " + array[indiceCoche2].getKilometrosRecorridos());
                   }

                   System.out.println();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes capturar la excepción con `try catch`, y dentro de un ciclo, si se lanza la excepción se sigue ejecutando el ciclo, de lo contrario se sale de el.

```
boolean identificadorNoExiste = true; 
while (identificadorNoExiste) {

    System.out.println("Introduce el primer identificador del coche :"); 
    int idcoche1 = teclado.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Introduce el segundo identificador del coche :");         
    int idcoche2 = teclado.nextInt(),
    indiceCoche1 = -1,
    indiceCoche2 = -1;

    try {

        for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++) {       

            if(array[i].getIdentificador() == idcoche1) {
                indiceCoche1 = i;
            }
            if(array[i].getIdentificador() == idcoche2){
                indiceCoche2 = i;
            }               
        }

    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        System.out.println("identificador no existe pruebe de nuevo");
        continue;
    }

    identificadorNoExiste = false;
}
```

**try catch** se utiliza para el control de excepciones, cuando surge una excepción con try catch la puedes capturar y decidir que hacer. El funcionamiento de try catch es sencillo, dentro de `try{...}` colocas el código que puede lanzar una excepción y dentro de `catch(...) {...}` el código a ejecutar si la excepción es lanzada. catch solo se ejecuta si dentro de try es lanzada una excepción.

**continue** es una palabra reservada que se utiliza para saltar a la próxima iteracion del ciclo.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que tendrías que hacer es controlar la excepción con un bloque try/catch como este:

```
try {
    for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){       

        if(array[i].getIdentificador() == idcoche1){
           indiceCoche1 = i;
        }
        if(array[i].getIdentificador() == idcoche2){
           indiceCoche2 = i;
        }               
    }

    if (array[indiceCoche1].compareTo(array[indiceCoche2]) > 0 ){
       System.out.print("El coche " + array[indiceCoche1].getIdentificador() +  " tiene mas kilometros recorridos con " + array[indiceCoche1].getKilometros());
    } else {
       System.out.print("El coche " + array[indiceCoche2].getIdentificador() +  " tiene mas kilometros recorridos con " + array[indiceCoche2].getKilometros());
    }

}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException r) {
    System.out.println("identificador no existe pruebe de nuevo");
}
```

Y si lo que quieres es que se ejecute de nuevo meter eso en un bucle también.