# ¿cómo solucionar error "exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"?

Tags: java, array

Me salta un error al correr mi código. A continuación los proporciono:

> Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException))
>           listaOrde.main(String[]) line: 44

Este es el código:

```
package firts;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class listaOrde {
private static Scanner op;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    op = new Scanner(System.in);
    String suc = "";

    String mes = "";
    System.out.print("Introduce mes a buscar: ");
    // mes = op.next();
    mes = "Septiembre";
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Introduce la Sucursal a Buscar: ");
    suc = op.next();
    String path = "/datos/2018/" + mes + "/xml/";
    // System.out.print(path);
    String[] files = getFiles(path);

    SortedMap<Object, Object> listCfdiMap = new TreeMap<>();

    //Map<String, DatosCfdi> listCfdiMap = new HashMap<String, DatosCfdi>();

    if (files != null) {
        int size = files.length;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            String string = files[i].substring(47);
            String [] foli = string.split("_");
            String [] exte = string.split(Pattern.quote("."));
            String fileName = files[i].substring(47);
            String rfcReceptor = foli[0];
            String sucursal = foli[1];
                            String serie;
            String tipoComp = foli[2];
            String folio = foli[2].substring(2);
            String fecha = foli[3].substring(0, 10);

            String tipofile = exte[1];

            if(files[i].contains(suc.toUpperCase())){
            listCfdiMap.put(tipoComp, fileName);
            }
             }

            Iterator<Object> iterator = listCfdiMap.keySet().iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Object key = iterator.next();

            System.out.println("valor: "+listCfdiMap.get(key)); 

        }
    }
}
 public static  String[] getFiles(String dir_path) {
        String[] arr_res = null;
        File f = new File(dir_path);
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            ArrayList<Object> res = new ArrayList<>();
            File[] arr_content = f.listFiles();
            int size = arr_content.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (arr_content[i].isFile()&& new EvaluaExtension().accept(arr_content[i], ".pdf"))
                    res.add(arr_content[i].toString());       
            }
            arr_res = res.toArray(new String[0]);
        } else
            System.err.println("¡ Directorio NO válido !");
        return arr_res;
    }
}
        class EvaluaExtension implements FilenameFilter {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String extension) {
                return dir.getName().endsWith(extension);
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Ya has revisado estas preguntas? [Solución a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130953/7334) y [Ayuda con Programa en JAVA : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/197531/7334)

Comment: El problema está en el `for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)`, debería ser `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` ya que si, por ejemplo, tienes un array de tamaño 10, las posiciones que puedes acceder son de la 0 a la 9, por eso debes hacer la validación de que i sea menor al tamaño. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Te sugiero aportar más información en tu pregunta para que sea de utilidad a la comunidad. Revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: No borres tu pregunta por favor, eso no está permitido.

Comment: Cual es la linea de código que muestra el error @PizzaSteve