# Resolver ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException en split string de java

Tags: java, string, split

Se tienen líneas en donde existen hasta 3 cadenas separadas por un acento circunflejo **^** con el siguiente formato:

```
campo1^campo2^campo3
^^campo3
^campo2^
campo1^^
...
^^^
```

En donde pueden existir 3 campos con información, 2, 1 o en el peor de los casos los 3 vacios.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    String line = "^^JJ05559";
    String[] datos = new String[3];
    datos = line.split("\\^");
                    System.out.println(line);
                    datos[0] = datos[0] == null ? "" : datos[0];
                    datos[1] = datos[1] == null ? "" : datos[1];
                    datos[2] = datos[2] == null ? "" : datos[2];
                    System.out.println("0: "+datos[0]);
                    System.out.println("1: "+datos[1]);
                    System.out.println("2: "+datos[2]);

    line = "JJ05559^^";
    datos = new String[3];
    datos = line.split("\\^");
                    System.out.println(line);
                    datos[0] = datos[0] == null ? "" : datos[0];
                    datos[1] = datos[1] == null ? "" : datos[1];
                    datos[2] = datos[2] == null ? "" : datos[2];
                    System.out.println("0: "+datos[0]);
                    System.out.println("1: "+datos[1]);
                    System.out.println("2: "+datos[2]);
 }
}
```

Lo cual devuelve la siguiente salida:

```
^^JJ05559
0: 
1: 
2: JJ05559
JJ05559^^
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:21)
```

Puntualmente mis preguntas son las siguientes:

**¿Por qué para el primer caso el split se hace correctamente pero para el segundo la segunda posición no existe?**

**¿Cómo puedo lograr hacer un split manteniendo las posiciones de las coincidencias y al mismo tiempo las cadenas vacias que se encuntran en la cadena original?**. StringTokenizer no creo que sea una opción muy buena ya que las posiciones se pierden.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Solución a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130948/soluci%c3%b3n-a-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: En esa preguntan no resuelven el "mantener las posiciones vacias"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomando la respuesta de SO en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values

Indican que efectivamente el comportamiento esperado por la función split es no retornar los valores que retornen nulo o que estén vaciós en el array final:

> Por lo tanto, las cadenas vacías finales no se incluyen en la matriz resultante.

[Java Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Sin embargo se puede usar el segundo parámetro de la función indicando -1 para que traiga esos valores nulos o vacíos en el array final.

Quedando la línea de código así:

```
datos = line.split("\\^",-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que realices una paso adicional, dado que no sabes a ciencia cierta la forma en que recibirás los datos, excepto por la estructura de los mismos (tres acentos circunflejos `^`)

Para ello necesitarás una estructura auxiliar (un *array*) que almacenará el resultado del método [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Una forma en la que puedes lograr el cometido sería la siguiente:

```
public class splitExample{

  public static void main(String []args){
    String line = "^^^";
    String[] splitted = line.split("\\^");
    String[] datos = {"", "", ""};
    System.out.println(line);
    if(splitted.length > 0) {
      switch(splitted.length) {
        case 3:
          datos = splitted;
          break;
        case 2:
          datos[0] = splitted[0];
          datos[1] = splitted[1];
          break;
        case 1:
          datos[0] = splitted[0];
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("0: "+datos[0]);
    System.out.println("1: "+datos[1]);
    System.out.println("2: "+datos[2]);
  }
}
```

En el código se inicia el arreglo `datos` con valores de cadena vacía.

Se divide el `String` y el resultado se almacena en el arreglo auxiliar `splitted`.

Luego se analiza el resultado del método `split()` sobre el arreglo `splitted`, y se asignan los valores según corresponda.

Como puedes notar, si el arreglo `splitted` no contiene datos, no se hace asignación, ya que se supone que la cadena original es `^^^`, como la de mi ejemplo, así el arreglo de datos queda intacto.

No sé si es lo que buscas implementar, pero es una manera básica de solucionar tu problema.

En cuanto a porqué falla tu implementación, la respuesta está en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)). La misma establece que: (énfasis añadido por mi)

> La matriz devuelta por este método contiene cada subcadena de ésta cadena, la cual **termina** con otra subcadena que coincide con la expresión dada **o se termina al final de la cadena**. Las subcadenas de la matriz están en el orden en que aparecen en esta cadena. Si la expresión no coincide con ninguna parte de la entrada, la matriz resultante solo tiene un elemento, a saber, ésta cadena.
>
> ...**las cadenas vacías en la cola serán descartadas.**

Esto último es lo que sucede cuando aplicas el método `split()` a la cadena `^^^`.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.