# ¿Cómo podria usar if en un JComboBox?

Tags: java, json, netbeans, jframe

Estoy haciendo un tipo de registro de un trabajo de mi instituto y no he encontrado en internet como hacer esto. Quisiera saber si se podría hacer que al seleccionar una casilla del JComboBox haga una determinada operación y que dicha operación se sume a una tabla, y que no afecte al resto del código y como podría hacerlo. También les pediría si pueden revisar el código completo, por si hay una parte errónea.
De antemano gracias.

Mi código:

```
    int valor, cantidad;
    valor=Integer.parseInt(txtvalor.getText());
    cantidad=Integer.parseInt(txtcantidad.getText());
    
    int sueldo_bruto=valor*cantidad;
    double desc_SNP=0.13*sueldo_bruto;
    
    Object[]arreglo=new Object[8];
    arreglo[0]=txtnombre.getText();
    arreglo[1]=txtedad.getText();
    arreglo[2]=txtdni.getText();
    arreglo[3]=txtfecha.getText();
    arreglo[4]=(String)cdestado.getSelectedItem();
        double bono = 0;
            if(bono==0){
                bono = 0;
            }else if(bono==1){
                bono = 0.07*sueldo_bruto;
            }else{
                bono=0;
            }
        double sueldo_neto=sueldo_bruto - desc_SNP + bono;
        
    arreglo[5]=txtvalor.getText();
    arreglo[6]=txtcantidad.getText();
    arreglo[7]="S/."+sueldo_bruto;
    arreglo[8]="S/."+desc_SNP;
    arreglo[9]="S/."+Math.round(bono);
    arreglo[10]="S/."+sueldo_neto;
    model.addRow(arreglo);
    txtnombre.setText("");
    txtedad.setText("");
    txtdni.setText("");
    txtfecha.setText("");
    txtvalor.setText("");
    txtcantidad.setText("");
```

Esta es la tabla a la que me refiero, en donde quiero que se haga toda la operación
[image: Tabla a la que me refiero en donde quiero que se haga toda la operación]
Este es el error que me da al ejecutar el programa.
[image: Lo que me salta al tratar de correr el código]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Resolver ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException en split string de java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274332/resolver-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-en-split-string-de-java)

Comment: Hola, como te comentaba en tu otra pregunta abierta para lo mismo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/500561/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable

Tienes definido un array de 8 Object[]arreglo=new Object[8]; sin embargo estás intentando asignar valor a posiciones fuera de ese rango (10): arreglo[10]="S/."+sueldo_neto;

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que tu error da cuando se insertan los datos en la tabla de trabajo. Intenta modificando tu código de la siguiente forma cuando hagas el insert de cada fila:

model.addRow(new Object[]{txtnombre.getText(),txtedad.getText(),..,..,..,});

Antes que nada tu modelo de tabla opcionalmente puede tener como no una definición, por defecto puedes usar la sigueinte:

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

Saludos,

Comment: no asumas, pregunta al autor de la pregunta, es más [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)