# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>

Tags: java, json, netbeans, jframe

Buenas hace poco trate de hacer un formulario con  tabla en JAVA y me sale ese error dado que tengo un jComboBox y le puse la condicional if para que cada que me diera el resultado de la operacion que puse. Creo que de ahi viene el problema, pero no estoy seguro dejo el codigo. O capaz del resto de rows que añadi con operaciones, no estoy seguro..

CODIGO:

```
private void btagregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int valor, cantidad;
    valor=Integer.parseInt(txtvalor.getText());
    cantidad=Integer.parseInt(txtcantidad.getText());
    
    int sueldo_bruto=valor*cantidad;
    double desc_SNP=0.13*sueldo_bruto;
    
    Object[]arreglo=new Object[8];
    arreglo[0]=txtnombre.getText();
    arreglo[1]=txtedad.getText();
    arreglo[2]=txtdni.getText();
    arreglo[3]=txtfecha.getText();
    arreglo[4]=(String)cdestado.getSelectedItem();
        double bono = 0;
            if(bono==0){
                bono = 0;
            }else if(bono==1){
                bono = 0.07*sueldo_bruto;
        double sueldo_neto=sueldo_bruto - desc_SNP + bono;
        
    arreglo[5]=txtvalor.getText();
    arreglo[6]=txtcantidad.getText();
    arreglo[7]="S/."+sueldo_bruto;
    arreglo[8]="S/."+desc_SNP;
    arreglo[9]="S/."+Math.round(bono);
    arreglo[10]="S/."+sueldo_neto;
    model.addRow(arreglo);
    txtnombre.setText("");
    txtedad.setText("");
    txtdni.setText("");
    txtfecha.setText("");
    txtvalor.setText("");
    txtcantidad.setText("");
}
```

Comment: no veo la llave de cierre de tu else

Comment: cerre else de esta manera
if(bono==0){
                    bono = 0;
                }else{ if(bono==1)
                    bono = 0.07*sueldo_bruto;
                }

pero me sale este error
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 8

Comment: suena a otra pregunta que podrías hacer en caso de que las búsquedas sobre ese error en el sitio no respondan tu inquietud

Comment: Tienes definido un array de 8  Object[]arreglo=new Object[8]; sin embargo estás intentando asignar valor a posiciones fuera de ese rango (10):  arreglo[10]="S/."+sueldo_neto;